# using pandas.cut() and setting it as the index of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to find an easier way to run aggregate functions with my dataframe instead of extracting data  manually and running the functions separately from the Data Frame itself. I have soccer statistics from a team, and I want to run analysis and statistics based off of Age. I want to bin the ages and from that, run statistics based off of these age groups. More concretely, I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[20,30,22,27,35,33,22,28,29,21,28,33,29,27,31,20,25,26,31,33,29,18],
             'Goals':np.random.randint(1,6,22),
             'Shots on Goals':np.random.randint(5,20,22),
             'Yellow Cards':np.random.randint(1,6,22),
             'Assists':np.random.randint(0,16,22)})
df['Age Grps'] = pd.cut(df.Age, bins =[17,24,28,32,36])
df.set_index(['Age Grps'], inplace = True)
df.head(8)
```

Which outputs the following Data frame with the index set as the binned age groups:

```
| Age Grps | Age | Assists | Goals | Shot on Goals | Yellow Cards |
|----------|-----|---------|-------|---------------|--------------|
|  (17,24] |  20 |    3    |   3   |       13      |       2      |
| (28, 32] |  30 |    2    |   3   |       11      |       3      |
|  (17,24] |  22 |    10   |   3   |       14      |       5      |
|  (24,28] |  27 |    3    |   1   |       16      |       3      |
|  (32,36] |  35 |    1    |   4   |       5       |       1      |
|  (32,36] |  33 |    5    |   4   |       17      |       1      |
|  (17,24] |  22 |    14   |   5   |       13      |       3      |
|  (24,28] |  28 |    14   |   2   |       7       |       4      |
```

Is it possible to groupby the current index (Age Grps) to produce the following result:

```
╔══════════╦═════╦═════════╦═══════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Age Grps ║ Age ║ Assists ║ Goals ║ Shot on Goals ║ Yellow Cards ║
╠══════════╬═════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║  (17,24] ║  20 ║    3    ║   3   ║       13      ║       2      ║
║          ╠═════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║          ║  22 ║    14   ║   5   ║       13      ║       3      ║
║          ╠═════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║          ║  22 ║    10   ║   3   ║       14      ║       5      ║
╠══════════╬═════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║  (24,28] ║  27 ║    3    ║   1   ║       16      ║       3      ║
║          ╠═════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║          ║  28 ║    14   ║   2   ║       7       ║       4      ║
╠══════════╬═════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║  (28,32] ║  28 ║    14   ║   2   ║       7       ║       4      ║
╠══════════╬═════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║  (32,36] ║  35 ║    1    ║   4   ║       5       ║       1      ║
║          ╠═════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║          ║  33 ║    5    ║   4   ║       17      ║       4      ║
╚══════════╩═════╩═════════╩═══════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

What I want to be able to do is run aggregate statistics for each age group, such as Average Assists for each age group, Average Goals, Average Shot on Goals, etc. etc. Something like:

```
df['Average Goals'] = df.groupby('bucket')['Goals'].mean()
df['Average Assists'] = df.groupby('bucket')['Assists'].mean()
```

In order to generate a table like this:

```
╔══════════╦═════╦═════════╦═════════════════╦═══════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Index    ║ Age ║ Assists ║ Average Assists ║ Goals ║ Average Goals ║ Shot on Goals ║ Yellow Cards ║
╠══════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║  (17,24] ║  20 ║    3    ║        9        ║   3   ║      3.67     ║       13      ║       2      ║
║          ╠═════╬═════════╣                 ╬═══════╬               ╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║          ║  22 ║    14   ║                 ║   5   ║               ║       13      ║       3      ║
║          ╠═════╬═════════╣                 ╬═══════╬               ╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║          ║  22 ║    10   ║                 ║   3   ║               ║       14      ║       5      ║
╠══════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║  (24,28] ║  27 ║    3    ║       8.5       ║   1   ║      1.5      ║       16      ║       3      ║
║          ╠═════╬═════════╣                 ╬═══════╬               ╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║          ║  28 ║    14   ║                 ║   2   ║               ║       7       ║       4      ║ 
╠══════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║  (28,32] ║  28 ║    14   ║        14       ║   2   ║       2       ║       7       ║       4      ║
╠══════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║  (32,36] ║  35 ║    1    ║        3        ║   4   ║       4       ║       5       ║       1      ║
║          ╠═════╬═════════╣                 ╬═══════╬               ╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║          ║  33 ║    5    ║                 ║   4   ║               ║       17      ║       4      ║
╚══════════╩═════╩═════════╩═════════════════╩═══════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

I know I can extract the data in the form of lists and perform the statistics I need, but I'm trying to do things in a "pandorable" manner. Also I'm going to be plotting this data with matplotlib and I want to use the easy method of pandas and matplotlib API df.plot().

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) if need new columns to original `df`, but it return a lot of warning if set index from column `Age Grps`:

```
df['Age Grps'] = pd.cut(df.Age, bins =[17,24,28,32,36])
df = df.sort_values('Age Grps')
df['Average Goals'] = df.groupby('Age Grps')['Goals'].transform('mean')
df['Average Assists'] = df.groupby('Age Grps')['Assists'].transform('mean')
```

But if need aggregate data use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.Age, bins =[17,24,28,32,36]))
        .agg({'Goals':'mean', 'Assists':'mean', 'Yellow Cards':'sum'})
print (df1)
          Yellow Cards    Assists     Goals
Age                                        
(17, 24]            12   8.000000  3.166667
(24, 28]            18   4.833333  1.833333
(28, 32]            21  11.333333  3.000000
(32, 36]            13  11.000000  2.250000
```

Comment: This partially gives me the answer I'm looking for. I want to try a few more things on my own with this hint you gave me before coming back again to elaborate on what this resulted with. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Perfect, I can use what you referenced above, I Just wanted to avoid doing something like avg_goals = list(df.Goals).mean() for every single column, because i have way more than those listed above and that would've been a very laborious way of tackling this. Thanks again

Comment: I am not sure if understand. Do you need `out = df.mean()` for mean of all numeric columns?

Comment: No, My 3rd dataframe as shown above shows exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I'm basically trying to run an analysis on 3 different soccer teams (the champion of the league, the middle team of the league, and the last place team of the league) and determine if there's a correlation between the Age of players on the team and the place in which the team finished in the league. That's why i'm binning by age groups. And then I want to compare certain stats of those age groups among the three teams.

Comment: OK, so need aggregate for 3 different dataframes - each for one team?

Comment: correct, but like I said, my ultimate goals was to keep everything contained within one single data frame (3 data frames - 1 for each team with the added statistics of Avg Goals, Avg Shots, Avg .....) so all data is in one consolidate area. But using the .agg() method isn't that laborious as opposed to having all in one dataframe. The final step will be graphing all the data using matplotlib, and i've found that library  to be more user friendly when simply using seaborn and df.plot()

Comment: Hmmmm, so there are 2 possible approaches. First `df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], keys=('a team','b team','c team'))` and get big df with all data with MultiIndex. Then process data. Another approach is first process each dataframe separately and last concat 3 outputs. If starts with pandas, second approach is easier.